# VS CODE - remote ssh, prevent download project or files

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

[image]

I need to give access to developers, but how could I prevent the downloading project.

Answer (score 0):

That is why you have the `.env.example`, where you can add dummy-values. That way, the other developers can copy that and rename it `.env` themselves and adjust the values to fit their setup.

And if you need to share *the contents* of the `.env`-file, then I would suggest using A Password Manager program, since ideally password and sensitive information shouldn't be stored for sharing in a repository/project.